# Create an exe using Launch4j and Embedded Databse derby(Multiple Files)

Tags: java, derby, launch4j

I have a jar file in which I have used embedded database derby.I tried to create an EXE for that using launch4J but the database is not shipped with the EXE.I want to ship it with the EXE.If i am not wrong,the database is stored in derby.jar file which is located in the lib Folder where jar resides.So I need to combine those files to jar also ,if I am Right.How do i do it?
Any Help would be greatly Appreciated.